# Two almost same sites in one solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, solution, project-organization

There are two almost same sites in my new job. (asp.net MVC3) 
They did it with linked files. 
They put all files in one shared folder (witch is no in the solution) then they added files to 2 sites as a link (full site and express version).
These sites **almost** same. I gues it is not the best way to create almost same sites.

Any ideas how to do it better?

Comment: Encapsulate common logic into a separate class library and/or use a single site, but have configuration modify the behavior.

Comment: What to do with same views if we want to keep 2 sites?

Comment: Encapsulate common views into a separate class library and/or use a single site, but have configuration modify the behavior.